# 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in taglib-sharp.DLL WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I going to create file by using TagLib in WP8 this error Occured

> *A first chance exception of type 
>    System.TypeLoadException' occurred in taglib-sharp.DLL*

on the first line given

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(Path);

f.Tag.Album = "New Album Title";
f.Save();
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Try looking at what the inner exception contains.

Comment: Yes - step through the code and place a break point on the line that fails. There will be more details inside the `Exception` object that will help narrow the problem down. Please post the inner details.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I already use the break point to get the Inner Exception but it does not show inner exception it just pop up a Exception "A first chance exception of type System.TypeLoadException' occurred in taglib-sharp.DLL If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that the `File` type in your `TagLib` library isn't compatible with Windows Phone 8.

Most likely you're not using a correct assembly type/version for the library.

Comment: i think Claus Jørgensen you are write that File type in your TagLib is not compatible with Windows phone 8. But i download it from Nuget Packages from the VS Express for Windows Phone. If you know any other Library which is compatible with WP8 please do tell me. Thanks